# Rails S Hangs, port not disconnected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, terminal

Disclamer: I'm a complete beginner so please bear with me, I don't know how to name my problem, so checking the net for answers was troublesome.

I have a problem with port.

**Problem:**
I start rails server through this line of command:

```
rails s -p 3500
```

Another computer uses it. But when the servers hangs (closes the terminal and shuts down the server), it fails to start the rails server through the same port.
Complaining for (and claiming) **multiple socket usage**. We're pretty sure* no one else uses the same port.

---

**First Aid:** To get the server running, we restart the computer or change port to 3501.
Its a hassle.

**Assumption:** *It seems that it leaves the port connected.*

[Here I found another work around (quoted below)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125730/why-do-i-get-an-error-when-starting-ruby-on-rails-app-with-mongrel-rails)

> Find the ruby.exe process in your task manager and finish it

Is there an easier way to solve this problem?
I haven't tried the handy-work-around above, but I'm sure that would work.

Now, back to my main question:
***Does the server really use the port behind the scene?***

**Is there a way to prevent this from happening?**

**Who can be 100% sure? So forgive me if that's the only cause of this problem.*

***Edit:***
*OS: Windows 7 Professional*

Comment: For a process to use the port, it must be free on that computer, and that computer alone. It doesn't matter if it's in use on another computer. If you are running multiple rails webrick servers, and trying to use the same port, there will be a conflict. If not, then you will need to determine which process or service is using the 3500 port, and then turn it off. If you're not sure how to do that, look it up for your particular OS.

Comment: +1 for being thorough when explaining your situation.

Comment: @agmcleod added OS. I'll look it up. for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ruby.exe showing up in task manager under processes?  That's the easy way to kill it.  If it doesn't show up there do the following from the command prompt.

```
netstat -a -o
```

That will list all the ports being used by the system.  under the tcp section find the port that is running.  When you find the entry it will list the process id that it is running on.  You then need to kill that PID as follows

```
taskkill -F /PID 2632
```

The following is the line that I used on my windows machine.

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           fastone:0              LISTENING       2632
```

I killed pid 2632 as I was using the default rails port.  As to why it happens?  It happens in the linux world as well where most rails apps are deployed.  The problem is the ruby process is still running when a terminal window is closed etc.  The process disappears in the background.  The port is still in use and the service is still running.  I'm not sure if there's an easy way to prevent it from happening.  welcome to the programming world

Comment: netstat -a -o is handy.
Thanks. That does it.

Comment: A few years after a long rest in programming. This helps me again.